# SNMP Remote PING

Tags: centos, snmp, zos

Suppose we have 3 servers A, B and C. A is our monitoring server.
I'm trying to find an OID on server B to ping server C to find out whether server C is reachable from point of view of server B.
I found this OID in [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu101/remote.htm).
Is there an OID of doing this in LINUX?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can't find a built-in method of doing this, you can easily extend SNMP with a script which gets executed whenever you poll a certain OID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have used NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB and also I wrote a ping script which takes IP as its argument.

```
snmpset -v2c -c public  -m +NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB localhost 'nsExtendStatus."remotePing"'  = createAndGo 'nsExtendCommand."remotePing"' = /etc/snmp/scripts/pingScript.sh 'nsExtendArgs."remotePing"' = 'google.com'
```

Don't forget to place pingScript.sh file under /etc/snmp/scripts.
Here I entered google.com as default then from my program I change this literal with appropriate IP address at runtime.
By getting nsExtendOutput1Table.nsExtendOutputFull it is possible to read the ping time or whatever your scripts returns.